# Scheduled task in a service with Kivy / python for android

Tags: python, android, service, kivy, clock

I would like to implement a scheduled task in a service running in background with Clock.schedule_interval(mycallback,dt). When I implement this in my service, the code before and after this line is executed but the callback is never called. It's like the code is ignored and I don't have any error.
I read many forum and documentation, I didn't find anything on it.
Thanks for your help !

I just modified the example I found here : https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc

My *service.py* :

```
'p4a example service using oscpy to communicate with main application.'
from random import sample, randint
from string import ascii_letters
from time import localtime, asctime, sleep

from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from oscpy.client import OSCClient

from kivy.clock import Clock

CLIENT = OSCClient('localhost', 3002)


def ping(*_):
    'answer to ping messages'
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/message',
        [
            ''.join(sample(ascii_letters, randint(10, 20)))
            .encode('utf8'),
        ],
    )


def send_date(dt):
    'send date to the application'
    print('debug2')
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/date',
        [asctime(localtime()).encode('utf8'), ],
    )
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SERVER = OSCThreadServer()
    SERVER.listen('localhost', port=3000, default=True)
    SERVER.bind(b'/ping', ping)
    Clock.schedule_clock(send_date,1)    
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("debug")
```

Answer (score 0):

to get error and debug your code try that

```
from random import sample, randint
from string import ascii_letters
from time import localtime, asctime, sleep

from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from oscpy.client import OSCClient

from kivy.clock import Clock

CLIENT = OSCClient('localhost', 3002)


def ping(*_):
    'answer to ping messages'
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/message',
        [
            ''.join(sample(ascii_letters, randint(10, 20)))
            .encode('utf8'),
        ],
    )



def send_date(dt):
 try:
    'send date to the application'
    print('debug2')
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/date',
        [asctime(localtime()).encode('utf8'), ],
    )
 except Exception as myerror:
  print(myerror)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SERVER = OSCThreadServer()
    SERVER.listen('localhost', port=3000, default=True)
    SERVER.bind(b'/ping', ping)
    Clock.schedule_clock(send_date,1)    
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("debug")
```